# Django-storages upload FileField and ImageField to Dropbox

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, dropbox, python-django-storages

(Django 2.0, Django Rest Framework 3.8, Python 3.6, Django Storages 1.7, Dropbox 9.1)

I'm trying to upload a file to the Dropbox App Folder I've created, but I run into the same error at every attempt:

`C:/TrainerPics/UI_4.png' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*|id:.*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'`

On the Dropbox dashboard from desktop, the folder I want to upload to is shown as:

`Dropbox > Apps > DjangoAppNameHere`

Here's my setup in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'some_token_here'
```

where `storages` is also listed in installed apps. Here's the model field I'm trying to upload:

```
trainer_profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="TrainerPics/", null=True, blank=True)
```

I've tried this both with and without the `/` character, and tried this using `upload_to=DjangoAppNameHere` both with `FileField` and `ImageField` with no success. The documentation for Dropbox is rather sparse in the django-storages package, and doesn't describe how to set up a field to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is coming from the Dropbox API, and it's indicating that the supplied path doesn't match the expected format. That is, when uploading to Dropbox via the Dropbox API, you're expected to supply the desired path for the uploaded file, in a format that matches the supplied pattern.

The most commonly used format for that is the first portion of that pattern, which is just a "/"-delimited path for the remote path relative to the root in Dropbox. For example: `'/TrainerPics/UI_4.png'`.

Based on the output, you're instead supplying a path that looks like a local Windows filesystem path: `'C:/TrainerPics/UI_4.png'`.

You'll need to update the app/configuration to supply the remote path instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Greg , any idea about how I would be able to do this? I'm guessing somewhere in my `settings.py` file, but I'm unsure how to implement this just for `FileField` and `ImageField`.

Comment: Sorry, I can only help on the Dropbox side of things. I don't have experience with `django-storages`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, just to help people who might have similar problems.

There are two options that I used.

1. Use a linux machine when uploading your files. This will allow the API to upload your image as it's probably the same filesystem as their servers.
2. Only use the DROPBOX API on the server, and use local filestorage on local development. Servers run on unix and it does not produce the error.